# "Overwrite" the type of a property in a derived type

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have the following structure:

```
interface Parent {
    children : Child[];
}

interface Child {
    name : string;
}
```

I want to create a similar structure, except I want every type involved to have a `flags` property, but I don't want to redefine all the types, since they have tons of other properties. Basically, I want to create the equivalent of:

```
interface ParentPlus {
    flags : Flag[];
    children : ChildPlus[];
}

interface ChildPlus {
    flags : Flag[];
    name : string;
}
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
type ChildPlus = Child & {
    flags : Flag[];
}

type ParentPlus = Parent & {
    flags : Flag[];
    children : ChildPlus[]; //required so every child will also have `flags`
}
```

Unfortunately, the type of the property `children` rather confuses the compiler (for good reason). The following seems to work properly:

```
let parent : ParentPlus;
let x = parent.children[0].flags;
```

But not the following, which is flagged as an error:

```
for (let child of parent.children) {
    let x = child.flags;
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I don't get an error. What version of typescript? What's the error that you get?

Comment: does `interface ParentPlus extends Parent { flags: Flag[]; children: ChildPlus[] }` work?